# Polymorphic setter for Boost::variant

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I am trying to use the boost::variant with template types. For example, I have a template type `Tag<T>` and the boost::variant AnyTag comprises types such as `Tag<double>`, `Tag<int>` and `Tag<std::string>`. Each `Tag<T>` has members of type T.
Now, I would like to put those variants in a container and simply assign values during runtime, e.g.,

```
for(AnyTag & tag: AllTags) {
    setValue(tag, getValueFromXml()); 
}
```

The function `setValue(AnyTag &tag, T &val)` must use the runtime type of the AnyTag tag in order to correctly assign the tag with the correct value.
My attempt to solving the problem can be found below and it makes use of another variant which included only the possible T types that could be used in the AnyTag (TagValueType).

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
class Tag {};

template <typename T>
class Tag<T, EnableIf<std::is_arithmetic<T>>> {
public:
    T value = 0;
    std::string address = "";
    T maxValue = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
    typedef T value_type;
};

template <typename T>
class Tag<T, DisableIf<std::is_arithmetic<T>>> {
public:
    T value;
    std::string address = "";
    typedef T value_type;
};

typedef boost::variant<Tag<std::string>,
                       Tag<double>,
                       Tag<int>,
                      > AnyTag;

typedef boost::variant<std::string, double, int> TagValueType;

class tag_set_value_visitor: public boost::static_visitor<void>
{
    const TagValueType & value;
public:
    tag_set_value_visitor(const TagValueType & val): value(val){}
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T & tag) const
    {
        tag.value = boost::get<typename T::value_type>(value);
    }
};

inline void setValue(AnyTag & tag, const TagValueType & val) {
    assert(tag.which() == val.which());
    boost::apply_visitor( tag_set_value_visitor(val), tag );
}
```

Unfortunately, this approach is not what I would like because for example during compilation there is not problem if I do the following:

```
AnyTag a = Tag<int>();
setValue(a, double(1.3));
```

but during runtime, the boost library detects the type mismatch and crashes the program.

So, my solution is kind of a type erasure that just postpones the problem.

What I would like to have is a setValue(AnyTag &tag, T &val) where T is the runtime type of the AnyTag.

I get that that's what the variant's visitor tries to do, but there is a problem in this case because when we construct the visitor we must know the type that we are going to use.

Any ideas or any thoughts about this problem?

P.S.: Sorry for the long post but I couldn't find a way to explain my thought process with fewer words.

Comment: In `setValue(a, double(1.3))`, how do you expect the compiler to detect a problem when the problem is the _run-time_ type of `a`?

Comment: Nemo, I do not. I wrote somewhere that what I am doing is just postponing the problem. What I would like to have is  (in "relaxed" syntax):
1) the compiler generate 
    setValue(AnyTag::Tag<int>&, int &val)
    setValue(AnyTag::Tag<double>&, double &val)
2) and then during runtime 
    polymorphically select the correct setValue(...) depending on the run-time type of the AnyTag.

Comment: I understand that dispatching cannot happen in this way in C++, so I was thinking that maybe someone knows a trick (with visitor pattern) that could solve this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use¹ a binary visitor.

Implement the `operator()` to do nothing except for corresponding types.

Handle mismatches to taste (I return a boolean indicating success):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f052f80223ba96a)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace boost;

template <typename T>
struct Tag {
    T value;
};

using Types   = mpl::vector<std::string, double, int>;
using Tags    = mpl::transform<Types, Tag<mpl::_1> >::type;

using Variant = make_variant_over<Types>::type;
using AnyTag  = make_variant_over<Tags>::type;

namespace mydetail {
    struct assign_to : boost::static_visitor<bool> {
        template <typename V> bool operator()(Tag<V>& tagged, V const& value) const {
            tagged.value = value;
            return true;
        }

        template <typename T, typename V> bool operator()(T&&, V&&) const {
            return false;
        }
    };
}

bool setValue(AnyTag &tag, Variant const& val) {
    return boost::apply_visitor(mydetail::assign_to(), tag, val);
}

int main() {
    AnyTag t;

    t = Tag<std::string>();

    // corresponding type assigns and returns true:
    assert(setValue(t, "yes works"));

    // mismatch: no effect and returns false:
    assert(!setValue(t, 42));
    assert(!setValue(t, 3.1415926));
}
```

¹ If I understood your goal correctly. I've focused on the *"What I would like to have is a setValue(AnyTag &tag, T &val) where T is the runtime type of the AnyTag."* part of the request.

Comment: Thank you very much, sehe. This is exactly what I wanted. Unfortunately, I cannot up-vote your answer because I do not have enough reputation points. 
I see the trick that you did and I didn't think at all in this way. 
Also, you brought into my attention the boost::mpl, so that I do not repeat these type declarations.
Thanks again!

Comment: Hah! I'm glad you noticed that tiny detail with the typelist transform :) Cheers